# How do I change the version of my SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am using sql server 2012 express.But when i execute '@@version' query it is showing "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00" and most of the queries like 'fetch' is not working anymore.How can i change the database engine back to sql server 2012?

Comment: http://learningsqlserver.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/what-version-of-sql-server-do-i-have/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
```

Comment: its returning an error "Incorrect syntax near '110' "..then i tried exec sp_dbcmptlevel database_name,110.then i got the error "Valid values of the database compatibility level are 60, 65, 70, 80, or 90.
"

Comment: This means that you really use SQL Server 2005. The only thing that has 2012 version is Management Studio, I think.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are talking about server not database. if its database you can go ahead by changing db compatibility

if your version  is showing 2005 instead 2012 , check version of sql server.exe , seems your version is not modified while upgrading. Advice to re-run setup , if this doesnt detect sql server then apply sql 2012 service pack SP1. this will update registry and dlls.